# fullcalendar- unable to get month and year of the selected month

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Here is the thing,

I am making a calendar view for users in my website where I can show their monthly meetings and that sorta information.
I'm using fullcalendar. There is only month view enabled. And there is, next and previous arrow buttons.

This is what I'm tryna do. When a user clicks on one of those arrow buttons, I will fetch the selected month's month and year info and pass it to a backend service using an ajax call to fetch his/her meeting and display it on that calendar.

However, I'm not able to get month and year info. I tried two methods to achieve this.

**Method 1**

tried to fetch it on viewrender

```
viewRender: function(event, view, element) {
  console.log(view.start, view.end, view.intervalStart, view.intervalEnd);
  console.log($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'));
  var date = new Date();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  console.log(m + y);
}
```

method 1 yields no results.

**Method 2**: I'm able to get the click event of the arrow buttons but year and month I get is always `2016` and `11` respectively.

```
  $('.fc-button-prev span').click(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    console.log(m);
  });

  $('.fc-button-next span').click(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    console.log(y);
  });
```

I commented Method 2  in my fiddle.

here's my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e06j2ce5/).

Code if you wanna see.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month'
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
      var nextEventLeft = element.offset().left + element.width() + 5;
      element.parent().children().eq(element.index() + 1).css('left', nextEventLeft);
    },

    viewRender: function(event, view, element) {
      console.log(view.start, view.end, view.intervalStart, view.intervalEnd);
      console.log($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'));
      var date = new Date();
      var m = date.getMonth();
      var y = date.getFullYear();
      console.log(m + y);
    },

    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    year: y,
    month: m,
    date: d,

    slotMinutes: 15,
    editable: true,

    events: [{
      title: 'Sales Meeting',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 30),
      allDay: false,
      className: 'fc-event-width-overirde'
    }, {
      title: 'Marketing Meeting',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 30),
      allDay: false,
      className: 'fc-event-width-overirde'
    }, {
      title: 'Production Meeting',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 30),
      allDay: false,
      className: 'fc-event-width-overirde'
    }]

  });
  /*
  $('.fc-button-prev span').click(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    console.log(m);
  });

  $('.fc-button-next span').click(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    console.log(y);
  });
  */

});
```

Comment: In your method 2, you are just getting the current time with `var date = new Date();`, that is why you are always getting 2016 and 11. You should get date from the calendar, maybe with `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate')`

Comment: If the current month view is Dec 2016, and I click previous button. Using your code, I'm getting  Date {Thu Dec 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)} instead of November date. @ivn

Comment: And if you click again, you will get November (but you see October)...,  and it will always be one month off. That is because on `click` event you are getting the date from calendar current state, not after transition. So, either you add/remove one month based on the next/prev arrow clicked, or even better dig more through fullcalendar doc to find out how to get dates after transition...

Answer (score 0):

this is a working code for same requirement. full calendar pass start date and end date of calendar in UNIX system format implicitly.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
   left: 'prev,next',
   center: 'title',
   right: ''
  },
  editable: true,
     eventSources: [{
      url: ' your url.. ',
             type: 'POST',
             data: {
               dataType: 'json',
         pagination : true,
         viewType : 'calendar',
      ..... your params goes here ,
             },
             error: function() {
                 alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
             }
     }]
  ,
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) 
  {
   
   
  var clickdDate =$.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, "dd MMM yyyy");
  
   // do something with clickdDate in calendar if want
        
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get complete date so you can modify it for getting year and month

```
var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').format().split('-');
```

moment[0] -> for year
 moment[1] -> for date